# Paging mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've a page which is already SEO friendly by using mod_rewrite. Problem is, now I need to add paging there. I could not rewrite paging part.

BTW, all the following pages generated by a single file: list.php

Here are the pages:

```
domain.com/list/ - this page loads different data when there is no slug found
domain.com/list/movies/ - this page loads specific data since there is slug found
```

Above pages are done with following rules & they work smoothly:

```
RewriteRule ^(list)\/$              $1.php [L]
RewriteRule ^list/(.*)$         list.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Now I need to implement following URL:

```
domain.com/list.php?slug=movies&page=2
```

To:

```
domain.com/list/movies/page-2.html
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^list/(.+)/page-([0-9]+)\.html$ /list.php?slug=$1&page=$2 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried this but here it's not working! Thank you!

Comment: Its not working is really not a proper problem statement. Could you be more specific about the issue you are having? What url are you trying and what exactly is the error response from apache?

Comment: Sure. I detect slug to present data, when I use such rules it's returns GET value like this:  entertainment/page-2.html whereas it should be like this:  entertainment/

Comment: Sorry, i didnt get you. But when I go to **/list/foobar/page-number.html** my server internally maps it to **/list.php?slug=foobar&page=number** . I have tested the rule twice on my server .

Comment: It usually does but don't know why it's behaving weird for this paging part! Should I share whole .htaccess codes?